# Assign values to a record array in C

Tags: c

I've got the following problem. For a homework assignment I'm supposed to create an Heap-Array of the record "student" for 5 students and then assign some values(names etc.).
Now when I try to assign values to the record the way I did it before, i get an "expression expected before {" error.

```
Edit:

typedef struct student_t {
char hauptfach[128];
char name[64];
int matnr;
} student;

/Edit

student *students;
students = malloc(5*sizeof(student));


students[0] = {"Info", "Max Becker", 2781356};
students[1] = {"Soziologie", "Peter Hartz", 6666666};
students[2] = {"Hurensohnologie", "Huss Hodn", 0221567};
students[3] = {"Info", "Tomasz Kowalski", 73612723};
students[4] = {"Info", "Kevin Mueller", 712768329};
```

But when I try to assign a single value e.g.

```
students[0].hauptfach = "Informatik";
```

the program compiles.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

D.

Comment: "the program compiles. What am I doing wrong?"... Well, what you're providing doesn't compile for me.

Please provide a minimal, compilable testcase. Minimal means "showing only enough code to demonstrate the problem you're experiencing". Compilable means "providing enough code to compile on our systems without fixing typos or filling in the blanks".

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown your structure definition, but I expect that the string is an array of `char` with some maximum size.

To assign a string, you need to use `strncpy`.  Look that function up.

Basically, assuming that the `hauptfach` member is `MAX_LEN+1` characters long:

```
strncpy( students[0].hauptfach, "Informatik", MAX_LEN+1 );
students[0].hauptfach[MAX_LEN] = 0;  // Force termination if string truncated.
```

Oops, sorry I misread your question.  The above may still hold true.

You cannot copy over a struct like that.  You must initialise it at the array definition:

```
struct mystruct students[5]  = {
  {"Info", "Max Becker", 2781356},
  {"Soziologie", "Peter Hartz", 6666666},
  {"Hurensohnologie", "Huss Hodn", 0221567},
  {"Info", "Tomasz Kowalski", 73612723},
  {"Info", "Kevin Mueller", 712768329}
};
```

Or you can assign fields individually as you've shown.  Another option is you can replace one whole array element like by initialising a single instance and then copying like this:

```
struct mystruct temp = {"Soziologie", "Peter Hartz", 6666666};
students[0] = temp;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But where would I use the malloc() now? The homework is about heap stuff...

Comment: Oh, man, I misread twice (missed the `malloc`).  In that case, use my individual struct assignment approach.  There's no easy way.  Another option is to make a function that you pass all the data into:  `set_record( struct record*, const char *subject, const char *name, unsigned student_id )`.  Oh, I see this approach is suggested in Richard's answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try this out, although I'm quite sure there was something more simple intended, since it was our 3rd lecture on C and the overall design of our assignment just seems to be about making us use malloc(), free() and some pointer stuff by typing it into a *.c file and compiling it.

Comment: And what better way to learn than having to pass pointers into a function for initialisation...?  I expect this is the intention.  Those who do it the long way (filling all records field-by-field) will learn about refactoring from those who had the foresight to write a function.

Comment: strncpy doesn't assign to strings; It assigns to fixed width fields. There is no guarantee that the destination will contain a string. Additionally, your strncpy code looks obscure. Consider `strncpy(students[0].hauptfach, "Informatik", sizeof students[0].hauptfach - 1); students[0].hauptfach[sizeof students[0].hauptfach - 1] = '\0';` to remove the preprocessor definitions and shine clarity upon the code.

Comment: Additionally, `students[0] = (student){"Soziologie", "Peter Hartz", 6666666};` seems well defined by the C99 standard. ;)

Answer (score 1):

These two statements can't really go together:

```
1 students = malloc(5*sizeof(student));
2 students[0] = {"Info", "Max Becker", 2781356};
```

(1) says that you want to dynamically allocate memory at run-time.

(2) says that you want to assign the values you list to a fixed address at compile-time. Unfortunately, the compiler cannot know what the address of `students[0]` is ahead of time, so it cannot do what you would like.

I'd suggest you create a helper function:

```
void initstudent(student *s, const char hf[], const char name[], int matnr){
  strncpy(s->hauptfach, hf, MAXLEN);
  strncpy(s->name, name, MAXLEN);
  s->matnr=matnr;
}
```

and then apply this to each of your students.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess this is not what I'm supposed to do. The assignment simply says "Create a heap-array "students" for 5 students, then fill the array with 5 students. The thing we are supposed to begin with is : student* students

Comment: "Unfortunately, the compiler cannot know what the address of students[0] is ahead of time" Actually, the compiler will know that the address of students[0] is students, ahead of time. Clearly, the compiler can produce code to assign to students and students[0]. The code you address should work with minor modifications: `students[0] = (student){"Info", "Max Becker", 2781356};`...